# automatic backup of mysql database and automatically send backup data to gmail in windows

Tags: mysql, windows

all

I am using Mysql and Windows platform. I have a situation here like:

automatic backup of mysql database and automatically send backup data to gmail.How can I do this??

Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens if your backup grows above 25MB (wich isn't that much for a database - and gmail won't accept bigger attachments)?

Comment: I have a condition that backup wont grow above 25 MB and the backup is a zip file

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up a cronjob to backup the database (And optionally zip or gzip it), create the email, attach the file and send. There are many possible solutions depending on the kind of OS you are running etc.

There is of course the obvious limitation that Oezi has pointed out already with attachment size limits. A different backup solution would be better than this email based solution.

Comment: So, could you suggest me alert solution better than email based solubtion??